# Integral of $\frac{x^2}{\sin x}$ on the unit circle

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis

I need to calculate the integral of the function $\frac{x^2}{\sin(x)}$ on the unit circle (positive direction). To do this I tried to use the residue theorem, so I tried to  find the laurent series for $\frac{1}{\sin x}$, but I couldn't, any help?

Comment: $\frac{z^2}{\sin(z)}$ is a holomorphic function over the region $\|z\|\leq 1$, so the integral is simply zero.

Comment: How can I see the singularity at $z=0$ is removable?

Comment: The $\sin$ function has simple zeroes at $\pi\mathbb{Z}$ only and the Taylor series of $\sin(z)$ at $z=0$ is $z-\frac{z^3}{6}+\ldots$.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio does my solution look good?

Comment: It looks fine. $\phantom{}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did this at the end:

Notice $\sin(z)=z-\frac{z^3}{3!}\dots$, then $\sin(z)=z(1-\frac{z^2}{3!}\dots)$. Notice the second taylor series has an inverse, say $a_0+a_1z+\dots$.

Then $\frac{1}{\sin(z)}=a_0z^{-1}+a_1+a_2z+\dots$, and so $\frac{z^2}{\sin(z)}=a_0z+a_1x^2+\dots$. SO the residue is zero.